# Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-0.13.6/lib/src/io_client.dart:94:7: Error: 'arthrow' isn't a type

Tags: ios, flutter, emulation

Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-0.13.6/lib/src/io_client.dart:94:7: Error: 'arthrow' isn't a type.
io_client.dart:94
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

I tried to clean flutter